# Unity not loading project properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, load, project, scene

Me and some of my mates work together on a project in Unity. When I try to load the project, one of them gave to me (via Dropbox or USB-Stick, doesn't matter), I keep seeing the empty Hierarchy-window (I don't even see a main camera), although he created some objects in the scene.

The scene is definetly loaded in the editor, the name of the scene is shown at the top of the editor. I am not even able to instantiate a prefab in that scene, prefabs from the project are shown with a grey file-symbol, not with the normal blue "prefab-symbol".

By the way: We are using Unity 5.0.x

I hope you have a solution for my problem :)

Comment: Have you enabled the meta files? *Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor -> Version Control Mode -> Visible Meta Files* ; and switch to Force Text in *Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor -> Asset Serialization Mode*. Then save your project, share it and it should work. (and don't forget to save the scene)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a wrong setting of the meta-files and a version-conflict of Unity. The project was created with Unity 5.0.0, opening it with Unity 5.0.1 did not work.