# Default Unity tutorials cannot be loaded

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity 3D, and recently all default Unity tutorials stopped displaying under Unity → Learn → Tutorial Projects. Instead, it throws  error message "The tutorials could not be loaded", and all research towards this issues leads to dead end.

Interestingly, the other options viz "Resources" and "Links" are also not working and throws up similar error messages.

I am using Unity version 2018.3.0f2.

I have made sure the internet is working, and Googled and searched Unity support website for possible resolution but all efforts have been futile thus far. I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling Unity but still there are no tutorials there or the error message is still there.

I have tried the steps mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971371/unity-not-loading-project-properly) and followed the procedure of changing the option under Edit → Project Settings → Editor → Version Control Mode → Visible Meta Files; and switched to Force Text in Edit → Project Settings → Editor → Asset Serialization Mode, and none of this fixes the problem.

Comment: Were you able to try this again with success?

Comment: Why was this down voted? While searching online on any of the platforms (Google, Unity website and even here), there weren't any pointers towards any information pertaining to this specific issue. So I feel that this is a genuine issue which I had thoroughly investigated (even going to the extend of reaching out to Unity support, to which they never responded) and waited more than a couple of days to post it here for solution and info, and any future reference to similar issue could be fixed with information provided here.

Comment: @akaykay I started Unity today and it does show the tutorials list now, however, upon opening any one of the default tutorial, Unity shows it as loading and once it finishes loading, it just shows the "Scene" & "Game" pane, without the tutorial window. Something is definitely wrong which needs fixing.

Comment: Many of the tutorials exist online at https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials. If this continues to be a problem, I recommend posting on Unity's forums directly. In the past when I've accessed tutorial content straight from the Unity editor the download and setup has been slow.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment but I can't so I guess this will have to be an answer.

Some of Unity's sites seem to be currently down, I don't know the cause but I'm sure they'll fix it soon.

This is likely the cause of your issue.